# Dynamic crm 2015 remove task entity from activites

Tags: dynamics-crm

[image]

how to remove task entity from activites.

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking about removing activities from quick create bar, XrmToolbox won't help. There is no supported way, that you could achieve this.

Check this community question: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/119887

P.S. XrmToolbox only allow you to edit normal menu (sales,marketing,...), not quick create menu.

Answer (score -1):

you can use the XRMTOOLBOX whit this link https://xrmtoolbox.codeplex.com/

Whit this tool you can edit the sitemap of the CRM and is very friendly to use.

1- connect to your organization

2- on SiteMap Editor.

3- Click on Load Site Map and after that just select the area and you can customize your site map.

Cheers,
Jorge

Comment: I want only hide task  from menu .

Comment: Exactly you can use this tool and you delete on the sitemap, this is only going to delete from the menu or you can modify the XML of the solution. but use this tool is pretty good and easy to use and do exactly what you are asking.

Comment: I have download and connect to xemtoolbox but no any one entity find like  email ,task etc.